# How to convert single json array to row

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying json array column value convert to row.

That's my table:

```
id | json_v          |
1  | ["1", "3"]      |
2  | ["4", "5", "6"] |
3  | ["7", "8"]      |
```

I want to get just simple result:

```
json_v
1
2
3
4
...
```

I found this code:

```
select json_array_elements(json_v::json) from table_name where id=1
```

it worked. But when I tried get all:

```
select a from table_name t, json_array_elements((t.json_v)::json) a
```

I'm getting error:

> SQL Error [22023]: ОШИБКА: вызывать json_array_elements со скаляром нельзя (you cannot call json_array_elements with a scalar)

So how I can convert all json array values to row?

Comment: Where did you get the value `2` of `json_v` from?

Comment: your query is working fine https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z, but sql error 22023 means `invalid identifier` maybe somewhere on your code.

Comment: @Andronicus json_v collumn's type is jsonb and contain array value

Comment: @user2772197, either its varchar or jsonb, but you are casting it to json, it should work.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ I'm in shock, why in my mashin not working? My postgres vaersion is 10.6, maybe this is the reason

Comment: I tried posgresql versions 9.4 to 12

Comment: [no problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=45da89ceba32b2ddfbb629b755690ca0), as @Metal already mentioned.

Comment: Not the reason for your problem, but: if the column is defined as `jsonb` then casting it to `json` doesn't really make sense. You can use `jsonb_array_elements(t.json_v)` and get rid of the useless casting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried to change json_v column type to just json and varchar but it not help me. I all ready getting error code: ```SQL Error [22023]: ОШИБКА: вызывать json_array_elements со скаляром нельзя (you cannot call json_array_elements with a scalar)```. I don't no what's that error code for me.

Comment: That error means your JSON column does not contain an array as shown

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but when I tried get by ID code works: ```select json_array_elements(json_v::json) from table_name where id=1```

Comment: I found a reason, it turn out when json_v column is null or just empty. Thank you all for the help.